# How to get my Node API container to respond to changes in files?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker. I created a Node-MongoDB container. But I am running into a problem... Every time I update one of my files in the Node API the server does not update. Even if I shut down the container and restart it, the server does not respond to any updates. The was I am dealing with this problem is by removing the image and re-running the `docker-compose up` command. There has to be an easier way that this to do this. Thanks in advance

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: docker-node
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```

Comment: I use docker heavily for development and I don't have that issue, but in order for anyone be able to help, you need to provide your `Dockerfile` and docker-compose.yml` files.

Comment: You can run Node directly on your host, without Docker; your system probably even has it installed already.  You can use this in combination with a Docker-hosted database.

Comment: how do you have the file in your container ? if you user `COPY` in the dockerfile then you have to re-build the image. so it will copy it again with the changes. and the easy option is volume in yml file, `volumes:  -/my/path:/container/path`

Comment: @Exadra37 I added the files

Answer (score 1):

For what you are trying to achieve its not necessary to have a custom Dockerfile, and in order to have the changes made in your editor reflected inside the docker container, you need to map them by using docker volumes.

> **NOTE:** I am in a corporate environment, thus behind a firewall, therefore I cannot test the file I am about to give you.

Try this Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  install:
    image: node:10
    container_name: docker-node-install
    user: "node"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    command: "npm install"
    volumes:
      - "${PWD}:/home/node/app"
  app:
    image: node:10
    container_name: docker-node
    user: "node"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    command: "npm start"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "${PWD}:/home/node/app"
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```

**To install your npm packages**

```
docker-compose run install
```

**To run your app:**

```
docker-compose up app
```

or in detached mode

```
docker-compose up -d app
```

If in detached mode you can follow the logs at any time with:

```
docker-compose logs -f app
```

Let me know if it works ;)